# Splitting/Merging 3gp files using a java library

Tags: java, video, video-processing, 3gp

I'm wondering if there's a java library out there that can manipulate 3gp files.  Mostly I'm interested in splitting or merging existing video files.

I've looked at JMF (java media framework), but it doesn't support 3gp…and FFmpeg looks promising, but it's not clear that the library allows splitting/merging of existing files.

Does such a library exist?

Answer (score 0):

Try Xuggler http://www.xuggle.com/ (its FREE btw)

Comment: Xuggler uses FFmpeg and really is just a wrapper for it with some extra bells and whistles.

Comment: @Marc, true but it is one of the only wrappers still in existence that is kept up-to-date. You leverage the power of ffmpeg and associated libraries with Java.